# PHP preg_match match something or nothing and output assoc array

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match, associative

I am using the following code:

```
<?php
$pattern = "/(?<item>.*)\:(?<value>.*)(\{(?<flag>.*)_(?<level>.*)\})/i";
$subject = "item:value{L_300}";
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Which will output the following:

```
array(
    array (
      0 => 'item:value{L_300}',
      'item' => 'item',
      1 => 'item',
      'value' => 'value',
      2 => 'value',
      3 => '{L_300}',
      'flag' => 'L',
      4 => 'L',
      'level' => '300',
      5 => '300'
    )
)
```

My problem is that the subject will not always contain the '{L_300}' part, but I still need to match the 'item:value' part using the pattern.

Can any one help?

This may seem like a commonly asked question but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the correct pattern? The one you posted does not try to match "L_300" or any curly braces, it just matches everything after the colon.

Comment: You're getting `flag` and `level` captures, which you haven't defined in the regex. Seems like magic to me. That, or wrong code posted.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated it with the actual pattern I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a ? after the capturing group to make it optional. I also took the liberty to change some other parts of the pattern to prevent .* capturing too much in unusual cases (such as where there's an extra : or { character)

```
<?php
$pattern = "/(?<item>[^:]*):(?<value>[^{]*)(\{(?<flag>[^_]*)_(?<level>[^}]*)\})?/i";

$subjects = array("itemname:valuehere{L_300}",
"item2:anothervalue"
);

foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
  print "Subject:\n$subject\n";
  preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
  print_r($matches);
}
```

Output:

```
Subject:
itemname:valuehere{L_300}
Array
(
    [0] => itemname:valuehere{L_300}
    [item] => itemname
    [1] => itemname
    [value] => valuehere
    [2] => valuehere
    [3] => {L_300}
    [flag] => L
    [4] => L
    [level] => 300
    [5] => 300
)
Subject:
item2:anothervalue
Array
(
    [0] => item2:anothervalue
    [item] => item2
    [1] => item2
    [value] => anothervalue
    [2] => anothervalue
)
```